# How do we read multiline json string in a text file.?

Tags: java, json, file, io, gson

I have a log file. it has request json string and response json string. both are in there with multilines.
so how do we read json string in there.?

log file sample :-

```
URL : /saveEmployee
REQUEST PAYLOAD : {"employees":[  
                        {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
                        {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
                        {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"}  
                    ]}  
TYPE : POST
RESPONSE PAYLOAD : {"employees":[  
                        {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},  
                        {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"},  
                        {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com"}  
                    ]}                      
RESPONSE STATUS : 200
```

I want to get Request and Response json payloads

*Here I'm not expecting coded answer, but the approach.
would it be line by line check and validate until valid json string.? or another effective way.?*

Comment: You'll have to do some of your own parsing of the log file, before you hand the JSON string you have extracted to a JSON parser. Please explain where you are stuck doing this.

Comment: Incidentally it may be better to format your entire log file as JSON.

Comment: A perfect use for all those bracket-counting homework assignments that get posted on SO!

Comment: Here I'm not expecting coded answer, but the approach.
would it be line by line check and validate until valid json string.? or another effective way.?

Comment: Looks like the log format is "new value starts with `VALUE NAME :` and goes until the next line that starts with `VALUE NAME :` or EOF", so I'd parse each line until you find a value name that's either `REQUEST PAYLOAD` or `RESPONSE PAYLOAD :`, concatenate the content of the remainder of that line with all following lines until (exclusive) you find another `VALUE NAME :` and then parse the result.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, thanks I'll follow your way